# Spanning of Vectors on the Plane

Tags: vector-spaces

Problems:
Evaluate all the vectors that span the set of all vectors on the plane $2x+3y-z=0$.
Are all the vectors linearly independent? Give the explanation.

Attempt (source from my friend):
This plane is 2-dimensional hence cannot be spanned by a single vector but is spanned by any set $\{p,q\}$ where $p,q\in V$ are independent.

Actually I need more explanation for this problems.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't figure out what are you asking? What is "brief" here?

Comment: Where is " brief " here?

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 2):

The plane is nothing more than
$$\begin{align}
\textsf{W} &= \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:\, 2x+3y-z=0\} \\
&= \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3:\, z=2x+3y\} \\
&= \{(x,y,2x+3y):\, x,y\in \mathbb{R}\} \\
&= \{x(1,0,2)+y(0,1,3):\, x,y\in \mathbb{R}\} 
\end{align}$$
that is, any vector in the plane can be written as a linear combination of the vectors $(1,0,2)$ and $(0,1,3)$. Now verify that the set formed by these vectors is linearly independent, that is, if $$a_1(1,0,2)+a_2(0,1,3)=(0,0,0)$$ for some scalars $a_1,a_2$, necessarily implies that $a_1=a_2=0$ (which is clear).